# big amount of data in list like TikTok [react-native]

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a react-native app and I'd like to create a list of images and videos like TikTok, so it could be really long.
I've already followed the instructions for improving  performances, but the lag still exists, therefore I've spotted some libraries that could solve the lag:

> react-native-big-list
>
> recyclerlistview

Any suggestions to create an improved performance FlatList.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please post here code how you are rendering your `<FlatList />`, maybe there are two many re-renders or you are using too heavy components inside.

There are couple of things that can improve performance

1. use https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image for displaying thumbnails. This is must have solution if you are rendering list with images inside.
2. decrease amount of transparent views
3. use hermes on android (and on iOS too for latest RN)
4. check this doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/optimizing-flatlist-configuration